# Add column with static text on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net project. How can I add a static column with static text to a GridView which  is loaded with a dataset? For example I want a column `Check` which has values in every row Checked.

Comment: Add a dummy column and value in the query. You may show how you are binding the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YouText">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.isChecked") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Or if you just want static text do this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YouText">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Your text
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: i dont want to evaluate something. I just want a static text

Comment: how can i give a name to the column header?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            //static text or checkbox
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
gridView.DataSource = dataset;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Your static text will show every rows.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the static text with the dynamic bool?

You can use a binding expression.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    Check
    <asp:CheckBox ID="myCheckbox" runat="server" 
        Checked='<%# Eval("IsChecked") %>'
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnCheckedChanged="myCheckbox_Checked" />
</ItemTemplate>
```